# How to plot time series in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, time-series

I have some data collected for a week say between from 03/11/2013 at 8:00:00 AM - 11:00:00 AM.

How can I plot a variable x against this time for entire week? I am trying to use timeseries or plot. But could not establish what I need.

Comment: Assuming the data is sampled at a constant rate, can't you just use linspace and plot against that?

Comment: The x axis need to have 8:00:00 to 11:00:00 and y axis has variable data.@lgnacio

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetick.html#inputarg_tickaxis - try this